# Getting undefine while pushing records in array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to push value to associative array but getting define when I push it.

So when I will push multiple records in to my `arr` variable like below :

```
var obj = { name: 'abc',value : 0};
var obj = { name: 'pqr',value : 1};
var obj = { name: 'lmn',value : 2};
```

and suppose I want to get value for abc then I can get it like below :

```
var name = "abc";
arr[name];
```

Demo:

```js
var obj = { name: 'abc',value : 0};

var arr = [];

arr[obj.name].push({
                 key : obj.value
                });
                
                console.log(arr);
```

Comment: For starters, you're building an associative array, aka. an object. Using `var arr = []` is incorrect for this purpose. Use `var map = {};`. Then, just do `map[obj.name] = obj.value;`. Done.

Comment: `var obj = ` three times?

Comment: @epascarello : consider i have to push 3 records with value 0,1,2 so that was just an example

Comment: So why do you not make it an array as your demo??

Comment: Downvoter whats wrong with this question.Could you please explain as i tried something it didnt work out hence i posted on SO.What wrong did you find with this question

Comment: @epascarello:Actually i am having a form in which i am using this object to store name and value so each time user click on save button i want to use this obj to push records in my arr variable.So that is why it is not an array.

Comment: The title, and the body, of this question are in disagreement. The title says "getting undefine" and the question says "getting define". Neither make much sense. Is this a reference to a JavaScript error? If so, it's worth copying+pasting, so transcription errors do not confuse the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an object with arrays.

```js
var records = {}; //holds the keys with their array of values
function insertRecord(obj) {
  records[obj.name] = records[obj.name] || []; //if we have not seen the key, set it up
  records[obj.name].push(obj.value); //add the new value
}

insertRecord({
  name: 'abc',
  value: 0
});
insertRecord({
  name: 'pqr',
  value: 1
});
insertRecord({
  name: 'lmn',
  value: 2
});
insertRecord({
  name: 'abc',
  value: 5
});

insertRecord({
  name: 'abc',
  value: 10
});

console.log(records["abc"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont push to an array, put into an object

```
var obj= {
 abc:0,
 pqr:1
};
alert(obj.abc);
obj["lnm"]=2;
alert(obj.lnm);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this .declare the `arr` as a `object` instead of `array`.Because Array is not key value pair .And `arr[obj.name]=[]` declare `arr[obj.name]` the with array.Then only push the `Object` to `array`

```js
var obj = { name: 'abc',value : 0};
var arr = {};
arr[obj.name]=[];
arr[obj.name].push({
                 key : obj.value
                   });
 console.log(arr);
```

For multiple object use with `Array`

```js
var obj1 = { name: 'abc',value : 0};
var obj2 = { name: 'pqr',value : 1};
var obj3 = { name: 'lmn',value : 2};
 var arr=[];
function add(a){
var k ={}
k[a.name]=a.value;
arr.push(k)
}
add(obj1)
add(obj2)
add(obj3)

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: But what if i want to have multiple records like abc,pqr and xyz with value 0,1,2 resp then how you will do it.thats why i have taken arr variable as array

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do here is(If I'm right!), to **add the value of the object into the array with array index as the object.name**.

There is a function `array_push()` for this purpose.
like, `array_push($array[obj.name], obj.value);`

or you could use `$data[$key] = $value;` straight.
like, `arr[obj.name] = obj.value;`

Hope it helps.